# How to export attribute values with their ids?

Tags: attributes, magento-1, superattribute

I need to get all attribute values with their ids into a .csv file. Is it possible to export this data by creating an advanced profile or something? Need the easiest option.

Comment: Magento 1 or Magento 2?

Comment: Magento 1x. Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I went to phpMyAdmin and exported all data found in table eav_attribute_option_value. All attribute options and their ids are found there.

Comment: How to get it via csv file